# What is this symbol in Adaboost algorithm (SAMME)?

Tags: classification, boosting, ensemble-learning, adaboost

According to the original paper of SAMME algorithm (Adaboost for multiclass problems), it is described as follows:

[image]

The general idea is very straightfoward, except for this symbol:

[image]

The author didn't give any context for this expression, but i assume it is a function that takes misclassified samples as argument. I would like to know what it really does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indicator function?

Comment: Like a step function {0,1}? I don't really know how it comes to this

Comment: It is an indicator function. It is 1 when the condition is true, and zero otherwise.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Please provide an answer so i can accept it.